# Delete "Unnecessary blank" in salesforce pages

Tags: ant

I have some salesforce page. And I commit its to github. When I compare source code from github and salesforce, have problem. In salesforce source code have unnecessary blank. 
So, How I can delete unnecessary blank? May be use ant push?
Thanks

Comment: Whitespace normalization depends a lot on what ide you use. Which do you primarily develop in?

Comment: @AdrianLarson, I use Vim editor

Comment: @AdrianLarson why not write this as an answer? I think it's a valid one